# IOS/Storyboard: Create Outlet Property for Text of Tabbar Item on Toolbar

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I use a TabBar controller as part of navigation.  The VCs linked to the TabBar Controller have navigation controllers with an icon image that is the one you see in the tab bar, for example, a home icon for the home screen.

I would like to be able to change the text and possibly the image of the icon.  A natural way would be to create an outlet property but I don't know what View Controller to connect it to since the icon seems to be part of the navigation controller, not the VC itself.  I've tried dragging from the icon to the VC controlled by the appropriate navigation controller but it doesn't take.

Can anyone suggest how to accomplish this?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set tab bar item image/title in each view controller, for example in viewDidAppear

```
if let selectedItem = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.selectedItem {
            selectedItem.image = UIImage.init(named: "DefaultImageName")
            selectedItem.selectedImage = UIImage.init(named: "SelectedImageName")
            selectedItem.title = "Test Title"
}
```

Comment: how would you do that in Objective-C? Sorry not so good at swift

Comment: Got it to work with UITabBarItem *selectedItem = self.tabBarController.tabBar.selectedItem;
    if (selectedItem) {
        selectedItem.title = @"Home";
    } in viewWillAppear